# How many Wordpress database queries is normal?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and a developer developed a custom plugin. When I launched my site and more users registered on my site, the slower my site gets.

I was wondering how this happened and after some digging I found out that a page load is requesting about 590 database queries.

Is this normal or way to high?

It is a comparison site with about 70 company's with every company about 20 products, reviews ect.

Thanks

Comment: 590 trips to the database to load one page seems... high.

Comment: Seems high but really not a valid question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: It mainly depends on the installed plugins, it is normaly up to 200. Use [query monitor](https://hr.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin for analysis of db queries, and check [this](https://yoast.com/wordpress-performance-optimization/) article for database optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

590 queries per page load is insanely high.

Most likely you have a loop somewhere which is doing a query each time through instead of doing a single query, caching the results, and then handling the cached results.

Also, check out these:

- [mysql too many queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308747/mysql-how-many-queries-per-page-is-too-many)
- [reduce queries that have same result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900746/what-the-best-way-to-reduce-the-number-of-queries-when-the-class-dao-have-method)
- [Finding and Fixing Slow WordPress Database Queries](https://css-tricks.com/finding-and-fixing-slow-wordpress-database-queries/)
- [speeding up your wordpress blog](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/speeding-up-your-wordpress-blog-7-effective-solutions)